# I want to replace a specific word in a text file and save the results in multiple text files using perl or ubuntu command?

Tags: perl, replace, split

I have a file results.txt that contains the following:

```
the word: word1 is a not detected
```

And I have a txt file contain the list of words as following:

```
word1 word2 word3 ...
```

And I want to generate txt files have the same names of the words, and replace "word1" by the words in the other txt file line by line  as follow:

file1 : resultword1.txt
contains:

```
the word: word1 is a not detected
```

file2 : resultword2.txt
contains:

```
the word: word2 is a not detected
```

file3 : resultword3.txt
contains:

```
the word: word3 is a not detected
```

....etc

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your word list contains white-space-separated words:

```bsh
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) printf "the word: %s is a not detected\n", $i >("result" $i ".txt") }' words
```

This `awk` command loops over all whitespace-separated words in the file `words`.  For each word (`$i`), it prints the sentence with the word inserted in the correct place.  The output is sent to a file named according to the word, with the string `result` prepended and `.txt` appended to it.

No test for name collisions is made.

On a system where GNU `awk` is not used, you may want to do

```bsh
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {
    fname = "result" $i ".txt"
    printf "the word: %s is a not detected\n", $i >fname
    close(fname)
}' words
```

... so that you don't run out of file descriptors after a while (I believe GNU `awk` handles this graciously internally).  Note, though, that this means that the file would be *truncated* the next time the same word is processed, rather than appended to.  In both pieces of code, the output files would be truncated upon the first output to them.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it work for me very well. but I ve got a dot symbol in the name of txt files like this: resultpneumonia. how can I delete it using the code? cuz there are alot of generated files.

Comment: @HoussamDev Is your word list in a DOS text format (did you write it or produce it on a Windows system)?  If so, run `dos2unix` on the file before you use it on Unix.

Comment: My word list in txt file

Comment: @HoussamDev Yes I know, but is it a Unix text file or a DOS/Windows text file? The issue with a DOS or Windows text file is that each line has an invisible carriage-return character at the end.  I _believe_ that this is the character that is producing strange filenames for you.

Comment: it is DOS file. how can I delete it?

Comment: @HoussamDev A couple of comments ago, I mentioned that the utility `dos2unix` would convert the file from DOS to Unix text file. This would be the best option. You may also try running my `awk` code using `awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{ ... }' words`.  I think that adding `-F '[[:space:]]+'` may possibly help, but I'm not entirely certain (it would be better to convert the file with `dos2unix`).

Comment: thank you too much worked very well.

Comment: I have used dos2unix